# Gradle task dependsOn task in separate project

Tags: java, groovy, gradle

I am trying to enforce a dependency between a task in one project on a task in another project as follows:

```
task someTask(dependsOn: ':otherProject:someOtherTask'){}
```

But I get the following error:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':someProject:someTask'.
> Task with path ':otherProject:someOtherTask' not found in project ':someProject'.
```

I think the project `otherProject` hasn't been evaluated when Gradle tries to run `someTask`. However, I can't seem to find a way to enforce this dependency.

Ideas?

Comment: The task path should only get resolved to a task object at the time the task execution graph is built (i.e. after the configuration phase). Hence it's more likely that the problem is somewhere else (e.g. wrong task path).

Comment: I'm seeing the same issue but not in a trivial project layout. @Giovanni, do you see the problem with a trivial project layout? If not, what layout do you have that reproduces the problem? I'll try to reproduce the problem with a minimal project layout, too.

Comment: I figured this out. see my reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by adding a project evaluation dependency. In the build.gradle file for `someProject`:

```
evaluationDependsOn(':otherProject')
// ...
task someTask(dependsOn: ':otherProject:someOtherTask'){}
```